# I need help to figure out what code i need to drop duplicates

Tags: python, duplicates

basically i have this code

```py
while z<9:
    z=z+1
    dat = '2019-09-0'+str(z)
    mnodel = s.list (dat, dat, monthpath)
    p=0
    m=p+1
    lon2 = len(mnodel)
    for items in mnodel:
        while p <= lon2:
            if p< lon2 :
                lista= mnodel[p]['name']+' Fecha: '+dat
                p=p+1
                print lista
            else:
                break
    if z==9:
        break
```

And the output is something like this

```
2c:95:69:a4:90:ca Fecha: 2019-09-02
dc:a2:66:85:c8:d1 Fecha: 2019-09-02
64:77:7d:c2:1b:a0 Fecha: 2019-09-02
2c:95:69:a4:90:ca Fecha: 2019-09-03
f8:ed:a5:6a:05:82 Fecha: 2019-09-03
48:f7:c0:33:e3:a2 Fecha: 2019-09-03
14:cf:e2:28:2b:22 Fecha: 2019-09-03
f8:2d:c0:19:10:c4 Fecha: 2019-09-03
64:77:7d:c2:1b:a0 Fecha: 2019-09-03
0c:f8:93:ba:ff:e2 Fecha: 2019-09-03
c8:3f:b4:c4:16:52 Fecha: 2019-09-03
```

and all i need is add to the code something to drop or ignore duplicate values

Comment: Import your data into `pandas`, then use `.drop_duplicates`

Comment: instead of printing collect them into a set. then print the set. pandas is not required.

Comment: i can't use pandas at the moment i need something without that library and the set option returns me values with "," and '

Comment: you can iterate your set and print the items

Comment: The example is not reproducible the way it's been presented.  Also, based on the print statement, this is python 2.7.

Comment: because I am interacting with an API that's why you can't replicate the output/script

Answer (score 0):

Make a set to keep distinct values from a list.

```
all_values = ['2c:95:69:a4:90:ca Fecha: 2019-09-02',
              'dc:a2:66:85:c8:d1 Fecha: 2019-09-02',
              'dc:a2:66:85:c8:d1 Fecha: 2019-09-02',
              'dc:a2:66:85:c8:d1 Fecha: 2019-09-02',
              'dc:a2:66:85:c8:d1 Fecha: 2019-09-02',
              '2c:95:69:a4:90:ca Fecha: 2019-09-02']

unique_values = set(all_values)

for value in unique_values:
  print(value)
```